# Can you install pandas in Google App Engine standard environment?

Tags: python, pandas, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am trying upload a project to Google App Engine Standard environment that uses pandas but I followed the instructions here:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27

I am getting this error: 
    `ImportError: Missing required dependencies ['numpy']`

I am  not sure if I am on the right path.

Comment: Well, I didn't know that pandas uses C libraries.. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/7GAEp38KnOU

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like Pandas has a dependency on numpy, which includes some compiled C code and thus has to be loaded through App Engine's bundled third-party library system.

To fix this error, add numpy to your 'libraries' block in app.yaml:

```
libraries:
- name: numpy
  version: "1.6.1"
```

See [Built-in Third-party Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27) for a full list of all the libraries you can include this way, and [Using third-party libraries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/built-in-libraries-27) for more details on how the 'libraries' block works.

Note that if Pandas isn't itself pure Python, you still won't be able to install it on the Standard Environment.  The above config will get numpy working for you though :)

Comment: This is what I get when installing that version of numpy:

`Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\havilez\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-n7bfdn\numpy\`

Answer (score 1):

continuing on from Phillip Pearson, when developing locally you might run into "no module named _ctype" or "no module named _winreg" errors. You'll need to apply the work around below, assuming your using windows.

- goto \google\appengine\tools\devappserver2\python\sandbox.py
- find the definition of   _WHITE_LIST_C_MODULES = [xxx]
  add following two lines to the list:
  '_winreg',
  '_ctypes',
- try your app again.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that it is possible to use `numpy` in appengine standard, but still `pandas` has quite a few references native libs.

So no `pandas` in appengine standard until it will be aded to list of native libs available through `app.yaml` import section.

Comment: Please, provide more details.

Comment: can pandas be used in the beta python3 runtime ?

Answer (score 0):

**(Nov 2021)** Most of the answers here are outdated as this was "fixed" when the [second-generation App Engine service launched in 2018](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/introducing-app-engine-second-generation-runtimes-and-python-3-7). You can develop & deploy Python apps in a more idiomatic way on the platform now. You do have to use Python 3 however, as Python 2 is still on the legacy platform requiring pure Python code (except those w/built-in 3rd-party library support as mentioned elsewhere). Here is a simple Numpy and Pandas app I just deployed (3 files):

```
############
# app.yaml #
############

runtime: python39

###########
# main.py #
###########

from flask import Flask
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def root():
    dates = pd.date_range("20211101", periods=7)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(7, 3),
            index=dates, columns=list("ABC"))
    return df.to_html()

####################
# requirements.txt #
####################

flask
pandas
```

**Additional notes:**

1. You don't need to specify `numpy` in `requirements.txt` because it's a `pandas` dependency; having `pandas` is good enough.
2. There are no more "blessed" 3rd-party libraries (w/or w/o C/C++ code) requiring that extra `libraries` section in `app.yaml`... just put what you want in `requirements.txt`.

Here is the output when hitting the App Engine page:
[image]